# EntityFramework Linq To Entities bitfield / boolean issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm baffled as to why the following happens:

The scenario is that within Stcoxrefs (which is a pure entity not a derived version) there are two bit fields.

Using the following the int, char, varchar fields are correct but the bit fields are always false regardless of what is in the DB, although running the query in linqpad works correctly:

```
public List<Stcoxref> GetAllowedStockholderTransferOrganisations(int currentStockHolder)
{
    return (from s in Entities.Stcoxrefs
            where s.OrganisationId == currentStockHolder
            orderby s.CompanyName2
            select s).ToList();
}
```

Table Mappings are correct as the following will prove...

Using the following function all fields are correct, bit fields are no longer always  false and are set according to the data in the DB.

```
public List<Stcoxref> GetAllowedStockholderTransferOrganisations(int currentStockHolder)
{

    List<Stcoxref> test1 = (from s in Entities.Stcoxrefs
                            where s.OrganisationId == currentStockHolder
                            orderby s.CompanyName2
                            select s).ToList();

    return test1;
}
```

huh?!?!?!?

EDIT: Stcoxref is an EntityType, here are the table mappings which validate:

```
STCOXREF_NO : int           ->    StcoxrefNo : Int32
ROLE_CODE : char            ->    RoleCode : String
ORG_ID : int                ->    OrganisationId : Int32
ROLE_CODE2 : char           ->    RoleCode2 : String
ORG_ID2 : int               ->    OrganisationId2 : Int32
COMPANY_NAME2 : varchar     ->    CompanyName2 : String
INACTIVE : bit              ->    InActive : Boolean
SUPRESS_EMAIL : bit         ->    SuppressEmail : Boolean
```

Both InActive and SuppressEmail exhibit the odd behaviour.

Comment: I mean, can we see your stcoxrefs object?

Comment: I simply cannot believe that, if the only code change was that exta list variable, that that would cause correct/incorrect loading of your boolean fields.

Comment: the mappings look correct to me

Comment: Gah thanks for your help / time!, upon further testing it seems that the previous developer shared the context! Grrr... So performing the functionality within a Unit of Work it works as expected. The shared context must have consistently been screwing up just the bit fields. Even stranger was the behavior of the variable making things work?!

Comment: I'm glad you found the issue.  Like Martin said, that was hard to believe that it was messing up due to the code change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this as an answer as it kind of is an answer, but also so this question isn't added to the ever growing list of unanswered question here on SO.

Gah thanks for your help / time!, upon further testing it seems that the previous developer shared the context! Grrr...

So performing the functionality within a Unit of Work it works as expected. The shared context must have consistently been screwing up just the bit fields.

Even stranger was the behavior of the variable making things work?!